# How to remove duplicate records from datatable based on condition

Tags: c#, datatable, duplicates, delete-row

I have a C# datatable with following data

```
Name    Marks   Month
LMN     22      Current
XYZ     55      Previous
ABCD    100     Previous
ABCD    50      Current
```

I want to remove the duplicate names data if month column is 'Previous'.

Example, here ABCD is having duplicate enteries so I want to remove ABCD having month 'Previous'

So the result datatable should look like-

```
Name    Marks   Month
LMN     22      Current
XYZ     55      Previous
ABCD    50      Current
```

The approach I am thinking to follow is to get deplicate rows and then check for 'Previous' column value and delete it.
But it seems to be a long cut way.
OR something like `DataRow.Delete`

Can anybody suggest a simpler way to do this?

Comment: by which condition you decide to delete entry ABCD and not XYZ?

Comment: What specific value are you looking to delete in Marks column? It seems like you are looking to delete specific values not just all that is marked Previous in the Month column..

Comment: Yes!! I want to delete the row which is having duplicate 'Name' having Month 'Previous'.Example, here ABCD is having duplicate enteries so I want to remove ABCD having month 'Previous'

Comment: Why does your data table have redundant data in it in the first place? You should be retrieving only what you need from the database.

Comment: @Jamiec I cannot change the query to retrieve this record as it is used in multiple places. So thought of changing datatable instead